# A different way to check the type of a list

Tags: python

```
list = [1,2,3]
print(type(list) == list) # Prints False
```

Other than changing the name of the list, is there another way to check the type of this list? (Because I have already referenced the list variable a lot of times in my code and it is pretty hard to change all of them.)

Comment: You'd use `isinstance(obj, list)` but you **need** to rename your variable. `list` is a terrible name for a variable anyway since it says nothing about the data it holds

Answer (score 4):

Your code justly returns `False`, as you replaced the original meaning of list by your list. You shouldn't use the names of Python builtins as variable names.

So, change the name of your list and it will work as expected.

If it's too late for that, as you suggest in the edit to your question, you can still access the original `list` with:

```
list = [1,2,3]
print(type(list) == __builtins__.list) 
# True
```

Or, the more recommended way, using `isinstance` instead of `type(...) == ...`:

```
print(isinstance(list, __builtins__.list))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are shadowing the built-in `list`

```
l = [1,2,3]
print(type(l) == list) # True
```

`type(list)` gives `<class 'list'>`, which is not `[1,2,3]`.

You can use one of the options suggested by @ThierryLathuille, but the best practice will be renaming the `list` variable, you shouldn't use built-in names as variables names.